# creating linked list in c++ with not creating a pointer to node but actually creatinf

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create linked list in C++ but if isn't printing the all element in the linked list .It is printing only the last element added to the list. I am adding at the beginning of the list.

I am trying to create a linked list with a function of adding at the beginning. When I printing the list I am getting an infinite output of latest element added in the list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.